# Unknown insects attacks on lemon plant

Tags: lemons

Hi guys I have lemons plants in pots in my home and I noticed that there are a lot of bugs stick to Leave do not know what are they. I tried to spray soap water but they are not dying  I throw pressure water on them which dropped it from the leaves but next day they were there on leaves again. So please guide me how to get rid of them and what is the danger level of it.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Update.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: is there sticky sap underneath the plant or on the branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely going to need a proper insecticide - something has laid its eggs on the leaves and the larvae are hatching out and devouring the leaves as they grow. I don't know what part of the world you're in and don't recognise what creature has laid these, but most likely some kind of moth; there's something under one of the leaves that's quite large and looks as if it has wings in the penultimate picture, but its not possible to see what it is clearly. Either way, soapy water is not going to do the job I'm afraid. The alternative is to pick off each individual larvae by hand and continue to do as more appear; some of them already look as if they're pupating, so this problem must have been present for a while.

Comment: ya they have wings they can fly around , i have attached that sticky paper with lemon plant and a lot of them attached to it now